# Create paper topography anaglyph map that can be visualized in 3D using red-green glasses

Tags: qgis, 3d

I've recently seen paper maps showing elevation displayed using a blue-red gradient that could be visualized in 3D with cheap paper red-green glasses. The effect is quite neat and I'd like to learn how to add this same effect to my maps using QGIS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

what you're talking about is an anaglyph map.

it's possible using standard QGIS symbology

here's an example I did a while back.

[image]

The buildings were given a size attribute (probably using $area)

The idea is for big buildings (by area) appear closer to the viewer, and smaller ones further away.

These polygons were given a rank (0=largest set, 1= next largest set, ... 5 = smallest set).

I then used 3 symbols for each building

- a neutral gray for the normal position, on top
- underneath the grey, a red copy but offset by 2^rank pixels to the left
- underneath the grey, a cyan copy offset by 2^rank pixels to the right

and a black background.

Settings...

[image]

To be honest I'm not sure how well it will work in print but it works (for me at least) on-screen :tried just now with a pair of red-green paper specs and it works.

the 2-to-the-power offset rule came about by trial and error. Basically, no-offset will appear flat on the viewing screen, and larger offsets will recede behind the screen.

For rasters and point clouds, SAGA GIS has an anaglyph option. You'll need to run SAGA_GUI, it won't be available from processing. Look under the visualisation menu for **Multiple Grids Viewer**. The options are hidden away under the <kbd>commands</kbd> button.

[image]